# Использование шаблонов

Tags: yii2

Я хочу создать шаблоны футера и хедера, чтобы подключить их к `main.php`. Есть ли возможность их подключить кроме как через `require`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если просто их вывести

```
$this->render('header');
$this->render('footer');
```